# Windows 7 Exception code 0xc0000005 issues

Tags: windows-7, exceptions

Whenever I try running certain programs (mostly games) they crash out (waiting for response, then wont load), the event log always has the same exception code (0xc0000005) regardless of program.

I have no faith in tech support being quick on helping me, can any one point me in the right direction of what 0xc0000005 means, so I can try and resolve this myself,

Thanks

Comment: First hit on Google says an application is trying to access memory it shouln't. Have you tested the memory? Made any recent hardware changes? Changed any settings? Installed new drivers? Disabled DEP to see if that's causing it?

Comment: I'm going to run a memory scan at some later point to try and work out if that's a problem, I read the memory stuff, but was dubious due to the fact search results for such questions seam to return back so much rubbish.

Comment: grr @ enter for submit.  The system I'm using has just had a new ssd put in with fresh install, but this issue was happening before the hdd got updated.  I'm assuming its more of a hardware problem but just wanted some clarification.  The whole system is new so didn't really expect any memory problems this early on.  I'll let you know how I got on with memory test & disabling DEP

Comment: I would definitely rule out a memory problem first. Burn [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) to a CD, boot from that CD, and let it run for a few hours. If it reports any errors at all, you have a hardware issue that you need to fix first.

Comment: Most likely a buggy driver, Bug Check 0x5: INVALID_PROCESS_ATTACH_ATTEMPT.....                   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559087(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Moab The error code is 0xc0000005, not 0x00000005.