# Apache 2.2.3 runs from CLI, unable to start service through Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, services, apache-http-server

I've happily been running Apache 2.2.3 on my Windows 7 desktop and laptop for some time (months/years) without any problem.  However in the last couple of days the Apache2.2 service in the Windows snap in on both PCs has refused to start.

When attempting to start the service the error received is:

> Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectly.

If I run httpd.exe directly from the command line then Apache starts up and I can merrily run my local development sites without problem.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to why the Apache2.2 service would suddenly stop working?

EDIT

The Windows Event Log shows the following:

```
Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.2.3.0, time stamp: 0x44c93502
Faulting module name: libapr-1.dll, version: 1.2.7.0, time stamp: 0x44c93456
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000038bc
Faulting process id: 0x19fc
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce0080a3cf20e3
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin\httpd.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin\libapr-1.dll
Report Id: e30ff5e8-6c73-11e2-aa69-9ce9ae4d78cf
```

Comment: Have you tried re-installing? Or go to "Uninstall Programs", select Apache, and click Repair (if it has a repair option).

Comment: @BenjiWiebe - yes I've been there it's made no difference.  A complete uninstall and re-install produces the same error.

Comment: Have you checked Apache's `error.log`, or maybe the Windows Event Viewer would be of some help?

Comment: The Apache `error.log` doesn't contain anything of use.  The last entry is back in December 2012.  The Event viewer references a faulting module of `libapr-1.dll` but doesn't shed any more light than that.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the full event log entry.

Comment: Probably isn't much help... http://superuser.com/questions/464143/windows-7-exception-code-0xc0000005-issues and also try a Google Search of `Execution Code: 0xc0000005`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been a result of a Google Drive silent update which has changed various permission settings on the parent folder as reference in the link below:

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/drive/apache/drive/4LWRozCv14E/gsG6cv0JCNoJ